# Android 4.2.2, How to enable TLS 1.2 for HttpsURLConnection?

Tags: android, ssl, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am developing an Android app for API level 16+ and from what i have seen by default TLS v1.1 and TLS v1.2 are supported but not enabled on Android 4.1+

I have used the SSLSocketFacory from here:

http://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/

Which i have managed to get working with the following example:

```
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

  private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

  public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, null, null);
    internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();

}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

public Socket createSocket() throws IOException{
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket());
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}

private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
    if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
        ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
    }
    return socket;
 }
}
```

and i am using the following to call it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try{

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getDefault();
        TLSSocketFactory factory = new TLSSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket();
        String[] protocols = socket.getSupportedProtocols();

        // this now has the correct protocols enabled for sockets
        String[] enabled = socket.getEnabledProtocols();



        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory());
        URL url = new URL("https://mysslsite/");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory());

        Log.i("", "");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I can see for a socket connection i now have the correct enabled protocols, however how do i enable these protocols for a url connection? how would i also verify that these protocols have been enabled for the HttpsURLConnection?

I have attempted to set the ssl socket factory for the connection but im not sure how to verify that the protocols have been enabled?

UPDATE:
I have modified my code as follows:

```
                    String myURL = "https://mysslservice";
                    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                    sslcontext.init(null, null, null);
                    SSLSocketFactory noSSLv3Factory = new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
                    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(noSSLv3Factory);

                    URL url = new URL(myURL);

                    HttpsURLConnection l_connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    l_connection.connect();
```

I have used the following implementation of the SSL factory

public class NoSSLv3SocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory{
    private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

```
public NoSSLv3SocketFactory() {
    this.delegate = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
}

public NoSSLv3SocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

private Socket makeSocketSafe(Socket socket) {
    if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
        socket = new NoSSLv3SSLSocket((SSLSocket) socket);
    }
    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}

private class NoSSLv3SSLSocket extends DelegateSSLSocket {

    private NoSSLv3SSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
        super(delegate);

    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
        if (protocols != null && protocols.length == 1 && "SSLv3".equals(protocols[0])) {

            List<String> enabledProtocols = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(delegate.getSupportedProtocols()));
            if (enabledProtocols.size() > 1) {
                enabledProtocols.remove("SSLv3");
                System.out.println("Removed SSLv3 from enabled protocols");
            } else {
                System.out.println("SSL stuck with protocol available for " + String.valueOf(enabledProtocols));
            }
            protocols = enabledProtocols.toArray(new String[enabledProtocols.size()]);
        }

        super.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
    }
}

public class DelegateSSLSocket extends SSLSocket {

    protected final SSLSocket delegate;

    DelegateSSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getEnabledCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getEnabledCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabledCipherSuites(String[] suites) {
        delegate.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedProtocols() {
        return delegate.getSupportedProtocols();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getEnabledProtocols() {
        return delegate.getEnabledProtocols();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
        delegate.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
    }

    @Override
    public SSLSession getSession() {
        return delegate.getSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void addHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener listener) {
        delegate.addHandshakeCompletedListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener listener) {
        delegate.removeHandshakeCompletedListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void startHandshake() throws IOException {
        delegate.startHandshake();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUseClientMode(boolean mode) {
        delegate.setUseClientMode(mode);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUseClientMode() {
        return delegate.getUseClientMode();
    }

    @Override
    public void setNeedClientAuth(boolean need) {
        delegate.setNeedClientAuth(need);
    }

    @Override
    public void setWantClientAuth(boolean want) {
        delegate.setWantClientAuth(want);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getNeedClientAuth() {
        return delegate.getNeedClientAuth();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getWantClientAuth() {
        return delegate.getWantClientAuth();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnableSessionCreation(boolean flag) {
        delegate.setEnableSessionCreation(flag);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getEnableSessionCreation() {
        return delegate.getEnableSessionCreation();
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(SocketAddress localAddr) throws IOException {
        delegate.bind(localAddr);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        delegate.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr) throws IOException {
        delegate.connect(remoteAddr);
    }

    @Override
    public void connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr, int timeout) throws IOException {
        delegate.connect(remoteAddr, timeout);
    }

    @Override
    public SocketChannel getChannel() {
        return delegate.getChannel();
    }

    @Override
    public InetAddress getInetAddress() {
        return delegate.getInetAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return delegate.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getKeepAlive() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getKeepAlive();
    }

    @Override
    public InetAddress getLocalAddress() {
        return delegate.getLocalAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public int getLocalPort() {
        return delegate.getLocalPort();
    }

    @Override
    public SocketAddress getLocalSocketAddress() {
        return delegate.getLocalSocketAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getOOBInline() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getOOBInline();
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return delegate.getOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public int getPort() {
        return delegate.getPort();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getReceiveBufferSize() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getReceiveBufferSize();
    }

    @Override
    public SocketAddress getRemoteSocketAddress() {
        return delegate.getRemoteSocketAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getReuseAddress() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getReuseAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getSendBufferSize() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getSendBufferSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSoLinger() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getSoLinger();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getSoTimeout() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getSoTimeout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getTcpNoDelay() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getTcpNoDelay();
    }

    @Override
    public int getTrafficClass() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getTrafficClass();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBound() {
        return delegate.isBound();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isClosed() {
        return delegate.isClosed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConnected() {
        return delegate.isConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInputShutdown() {
        return delegate.isInputShutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOutputShutdown() {
        return delegate.isOutputShutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendUrgentData(int value) throws IOException {
        delegate.sendUrgentData(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setKeepAlive(boolean keepAlive) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setKeepAlive(keepAlive);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOOBInline(boolean oobinline) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setOOBInline(oobinline);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPerformancePreferences(int connectionTime, int latency, int bandwidth) {
        delegate.setPerformancePreferences(connectionTime, latency, bandwidth);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setReceiveBufferSize(int size) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setReceiveBufferSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    public void setReuseAddress(boolean reuse) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setReuseAddress(reuse);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setSendBufferSize(int size) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setSendBufferSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSoLinger(boolean on, int timeout) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setSoLinger(on, timeout);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setSoTimeout(int timeout) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setSoTimeout(timeout);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTcpNoDelay(boolean on) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setTcpNoDelay(on);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTrafficClass(int value) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setTrafficClass(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdownInput() throws IOException {
        delegate.shutdownInput();
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdownOutput() throws IOException {
        delegate.shutdownOutput();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return delegate.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return delegate.equals(o);
    }
}
```

}

however i am getting the following exception:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb838faa0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x9da83901:0x00000000)

The SSL service has only TLSv1.2 enabled and SSLv3 has been disabled, however app seems to be still using sslv3?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue following the indication provided in the article  http://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/ with few changes.

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, null, null);
SSLSocketFactory noSSLv3Factory = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    noSSLv3Factory = new TLSSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
} else {
    noSSLv3Factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(noSSLv3Factory);
```

This is the code of the custom TLSSocketFactory:

```
public static class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public TLSSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        internalSSLSocketFactory = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    /*
     * Utility methods
     */

    private static Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if (socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)
                && isTLSServerEnabled((SSLSocket) socket)) { // skip the fix if server doesn't provide the TLS version
            ((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{TLS_v1_1, TLS_v1_2});
        }
        return socket;
    }

    private static boolean isTLSServerEnabled(SSLSocket sslSocket) {
        System.out.println("__prova__ :: " + sslSocket.getSupportedProtocols().toString());
        for (String protocol : sslSocket.getSupportedProtocols()) {
            if (protocol.equals(TLS_v1_1) || protocol.equals(TLS_v1_2)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can also check the server certificate using online services like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html to be sure that the server has the certificate you are enabling

Answer (score 2):

Your code already contains the line

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory());
```

which sets your TLSSocketFactory for all connections in your app that are established afterwards. Therefore the call to `connection.setSSLSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory());` is redundant and should have no effect.

Note: There may be an issue with already open connections that have been established before you call `setDefaultSSLSocketFactory` and that are cached internally and reused. Therefore it is recommended to set the default socket factory before you open any network connection.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This has now been resolved the issue was a SSL certificate issue, and can confirm that both methods are working for android api level 16+